# No ButtonGroup.clearSelection() method in Apache Harmony Java

Tags: java, apache

When tried to port my code from Sun JDK to Apache Harmony, The clearSelection() method of the the ButtonGroup objects was flaged as a compilation error.
What can I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Enumeration<ButtonModel> buttons = buttonGroup.getElements();
while(buttons.hasMoreElements()) {
  buttonGroup.setSelected(buttons.nextElement().getModel(), false);
}
```

Iterate through the group and set each buttons selection state to false.